# Is it possible to open a webpage which displays live video in full screen from terminal?

Tags: video

(Working on an RPi) I would like to open a webpage which is displaying live video content in full screen from terminal. By this, I don't mean having the web page itself open in full screen, but rather the video content. Currently my script uses:

```
chromium-brower --start-fullscreen --start-maximized (website)
```

I then use xdotool to double click on the video to open it in full screen. This doesn't seem like the best way to achieve this task though. Is there perhaps a way to load the video itself in full screen using one command? Further, is it possible to only load the video content in the webpage?

Comment: It depends on the particular webpage and how it is constructed.
For example with many (but not all, as Youtube can block this feature) Youtube videos, you can open them fullscreen using the embed link: https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX instead of a regular link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXX. But you must analyze this for each webpage individually if you can find such a link for that particular webpage. Good knowledge of HTML and often Javascript may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
But need to use omxplayer.

The line is like:
omxplayer --aspect-mode stretch URL-FROM-YOUR-VIDEO

Best!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with websites

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read well. OMXPLYER is for playback videos or streams. Sorry.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).